# relatedlisthover not working

Tags: visualforce, related-list

The apex:detail tag has an attribute called relatedListHover which does the following:

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the related list hover links are included in the rendered component. If true, the related list hover links are displayed. If not specified, this value defaults to true. Note that this attribute is ignored if the relatedList attribute is false, or if the "Enable Related List Hover Links" option is not selected under Setup | Customize | User Interface.

I have an org where I used this but the related list hover links are not coming up. The relatedList attribute is true as well as Enable Related List Hover Links is also checked in User Interface.

```
<apex:detail subject="{!Account.id}" inlineEdit="true" relatedList="true" relatedListHover="true" showChatter="true" title="true"/>
```

What may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have Accessibility Mode enabled for users who cannot see the hovers. 
You need to disable it in Setup--> My Personal Information --> Personal Information --> Accessibility Mode

https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/accessibility_enabling.htm

Comment: I checked and Accessibility Mode is false. I also checked my code further. Basically the page has more code apart from just the apex:detail tag. When I removed all the other tags and just kept the apex:detail tag, the hovers worked. So it seems something in the code is preventing this.

Comment: Probably there is a javascript code that hides hover links. I also tried this line of code and it worked for me too.

Comment: You are right. On further checking, I found that there is a javascript function called on window.load. It seems it is interfering with the relatedlisthover load.